# How to fix the "Required" field in powerapps?

Tags: powerapps

So i have a ReferenceProduct_DataCard1 which has:

- checkbox1
- comboBox2
- DatacardValue4

By default a user can select value from a combobox2 or create a new reference product by clicking the checkbox1. But once I save it and come back to edit form it says the field is required but I want the field required but not during editing the form. I tried to program the required field but it does not seem to work. Any ideas?

I tried doing:

```
if(Checkbox1.Value=false, DatacardValue4)
```

I think this is wrong

Answer (score 0):

Try following below steps;

- In the background where you are saving make the field optional/non require.
- In **New Form** select the datacard which you want to make required (only for new form)
- Find *Required* property of datacard and make it **true**. *Required* property will be in advance properties.
- Same way in the **Edit Form** make it **false**

If you want to make it dynamic for an instance if user check the **CheckBox1** then only **ComboBox** should be Required, try to put below formula in *OnCheck* property of **CheckBox1**

```
UpdateContext({Variable1:true})
```

in *OnUncheck* property of **CheckBox1** write below code

```
UpdateContext({Variable1:false})
```

Now put this Variable1 in *Required* property of **ComboBox**

Hope this helps!!